# How to pass String from ViewController to TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm trying to pass a **String** from **ViewController** to **TableViewCell**. (All questions I found on internet are about passing data from VC to VC or TabelViewCell to VC. What I need is from VC to TableViewCell).

Data to be passed: "testString"

From: ProductDetailVC.swift

Code:

```
class ProductDetailVC: _BaseViewController {
......
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let DestView: CheckoutItemCell = segue.destination as! CheckoutItemCell

    DestView.myText = "testString"
  }

}
```

To: CheckoutItemCell.swift

Code:

```
class CheckoutItemCell: UITableViewCell {

  var myText = String()

  @IBOutlet weak var lblShowText: UILabel!{

    didSet{
     lblShowText.text = myText
    }
  }

}
```

**Error Message:**
Cast from 'UIViewController' to unrelated type 'CheckoutItemCell' always fails

I think this is the right way to pass String from VC to VC, but I'm not sure if it is the same for VC to TabelViewCell, because I cannot get the value passed.

Please show me the correct code **in Swift** to do this by "**Segue**". If Segue cannot do this, please show me **an alternative way**. I'm a very new coder so please be precise how the code exactly should be. Thank you very much.

Comment: _"I'm a very new coder so please be precise how the code exactly should be."_ If you get help like this, you will again do this for the next problem you face which isn't good for you in the long run as a developer. Coming to your question, you should pass the value to the cell while your dequeue it in `cellForRowAt`. There are tons of examples out there. Look one up.

Comment: Segue is not meant for that, segue is meant for a transition to the other view controller. Also, you want to have didSet for myText variable. Does not make sense to have it for label.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll do some research on cellForRow at . And if Segue is not meant for that, what is the way to pass data from view controller to a table view cell? Thanks

Comment: you can use custom delegate to pass from view controller to custom cell

Comment: who holds your TableView ? what you are getting segue.destination value ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, VC and cell are completely different while VC is a UIViewController and the superclass  of UITableViewCell is UIView currently.

They are on different trees and can not be used in an interexchangable way.